# adding a specific value to a straight table qlikview

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a table as shown in the screenshot below :

[image: TableBox]

I'm trying to sum the quantity of a specific date ( 01/02/2021) to all the other field, i tried the following but i didn't get the results I'm looking for

[image]

Can you guys help me, i just need the results either in the script or in the front end.

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should sum the total aggregated the data for `01/02/2021` (aggregated by `Family`):

`sum( Quantity ) + sum( {< Date={'01/02/2021'} >} Total <Family> Quantity )`

Loaded data:

[image]

Result table:

[image]